# Update two different columns with a separate WHERE condition for each

Tags: mysql

I wanna update two columns on a table with different WHERE conditions for each one. I've looked all over and cant seem to find solution anywhere that matches the exact thing. I wanna have something like this:

```
UPDATE users 
SET col1= 'name1' WHERE id=3

AND col2='name1' WHERE id=10
```

Comment: Upadate isn't a word. Beyond that, I don't answer questions with 'wanna' in them; it's just a thing.

Comment: @Strawberry For a moment I thought there was a hidden MySQL command I didn't know about :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with a `CASE` expression:

```
UPADATE users
SET
    col1 = CASE WHEN id=3  THEN 'name1' ELSE col1 END,
    col2 = CASE WHEN id=10 THEN 'name1' ELSE col2 END
WHERE id IN (3, 10)
```

But I find this syntax awkward, and I might rather do logically separate updates not using `CASE` in separate commands within a single transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Try multi-table update syntax

```
UPDATE user t1 JOIN user t2
    ON t1.id = 3 AND t2.id = 10
    SET t1.col1 = 'name1',
        t2.col2 = 'name1';
```

or conditional update as Tim Biegeleisen said